# JQuery, add two handlers for the same event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several text inputs in my page. They have different classes added to them. Depending on the class they each have, I add an onchange event handler. Everything worked OK, until they all shared one common class, then I add common onchange handler again. The first oen gets overwritten.

Is there a way to add another handler and not overwrite the precious one?

Comment: Without sample code, it is difficult to help you. Can you edit your post to include 1) the code that binds the event handlers and 2) the code in your event handlers?

Comment: I am using it in conjunction with Farbtastic. http://acko.net/dev/farbtastic

Comment: It looks its a bug in Farbtastic http://code.google.com/p/farbtastic/issues/detail?id=6

Comment: I fixed it following this http://drupal.org/node/201684

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They should not get overwritten.

You should be able to do:

```
$('.className').change(function(){
    alert('here')
})

$('.className').change(function(){
    alert('over here')
})
```

And you should see both alerts

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/JEyTM/

Comment: You're right. I just realized it has to do with something else. Some of the inputs work and some others don't

Comment: @Neal: Sorry, forgot to go out of focus ;) Using FF.

Comment: @Marnix. you have to go out of focus in most browsers or the `change` wont get called

Comment: @Neal: I remember something else with IE8 =)

Answer (score 0):

All right, I resolved my issue following this [tutorial](http://drupal.org/node/201684).

It was actually related to a this [Farbtastic bug](http://code.google.com/p/farbtastic/issues/detail?id=6)